# BusyBox error please help me

Tags: fsck, busybox

This error is showing in my PC. There is BusyBox error:

[image]

Comment: Please post a picture of the whole error message

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please post the full error, verbatim so that we can figure out the problem. Also, please include details like how did you get here, where are you at in the boot process (if you're having trouble booting), things you've already tried, etc. Thanks!

Comment: You've not given many specifics; what Ubuntu product, what release of that *unstated* product, did you have a power outage or something that caused it; you've tagged `fsck` or file-system check, but we don't have clues as to what file-systems are involved (*commands vary on file-system being used; as `fsck` won't fix some file-systems*) but did you use appropriate `fsck` type commands for your *unstated* file-systems?  Did you remove any partition(s) or drive(s) before this occurred; if so please give details.

Comment: I don't see any BusyBox error in your screenshot. BusyBox seems to work perfectly fine. Can you clarify?

Comment: Do exactly what it is telling you to do.  It is saying to manually run `fsck` on `/dev/sdb2`.  So type in the command of `fsck /dev/sdb2` right after the `(initramfs)` prompt and fix all errors detected.  Then reboot your system when it is completed.